# Gnosis safe not letting transfer of tokesn

Tags: code

I have an issue with a safe that is a mutli sig and i have a token contract on there that it will not let me send any of the tokens it lets me and my others confirm it but on the execute function it does not estimated gas and says it will more than likely fail even when i increase the gas li9mit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was ensuring that I completed transaction operations in order ...You will see NEXT and PENDING...ensure that you are following the nonce/transaction numbers in order. In some cases there would be transactions to complete in a drop down format. Be sure to execute those before anything else. In one instance I had to add more eth. But that only happened once.  Hope this helps someone.